# Scrape the content inside of a div tag, which is not displayed as text

Tags: html, scrapy

I am scraping amazon reviews and they give an unique identifier to each review which I would like to scrape. However the identifier is never displayed as text but just exists in the following form:

```
<div id="R2XLFP626GRWEM" data-hook="review" class="a-section review aok-relative">
```

I want "R2XLFP626GRWEM" to be returned.

When using

```
response.xpath('.//div[@data-hook="review"]').extract()
```

I get the whole content of the div tag, which is quite a lot, considering that the whole review is embedded in it.

[Product I'm scraping](https://www.amazon.com/Kindle-Paperwhite-Waterproof-Storage-Special/product-reviews/B07CXG6C9W/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_top?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=1)

Content I need:

[image: content i need]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the id values by using CSS selectors instead of xpath like below.

```
response.css('.a-section .review::attr(id)').extract()
```

or by using xpath

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="a-section review aok-relative"]/@id').extract()
```

or by modifying original xpath query

```
response.xpath('.//div[@data-hook="review"]/@id').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

To collect attribute data using xpath use @. you can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)
For example in your case:

```
response.xpath(".//div[@class='a-section review aok-relative']/@id").extract()
```